# Negative Tsallis entropy?

Tags: entropy

I am building (many years later !) on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461241/tsallis-entropy-for-continuous-variable-in-r

I should make clear that I'm a stats newbie, exploring it out of curiosity, so forgive me if what follows is a question with an obvious answer.

It it my understanding that Tsallis entropy is always non-negative (i.e. `Sq(ρ)≥0`).

If so, how come it is permissible for Tsallis entropy for continous variable (`1/(q-1) * (1 - integrate.xy(PDF$x, PDF$y^q))`) to be negative ?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect it to be always non-negative in the continuous case? If you ask the same question for the usual (Shannon) entropy, which is non-negative for discrete variables, but the generalization to continuous variables, [Differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy), does not share this property. The underlying reason is that while *probabilities* cannot be larger than one, *probability densities* can be! For an example take a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1/2]$ with probability density $f(x) = 2\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2]}(x)$ and calculate its differential entropy.

Then calculate its Tsallis entropy with say, $q=2$,
$$
   S_2(f)= \frac1{2-1}\left( 1 - \int_0^{1/2} 2^2\; dx\right) = 1-2=-1
$$

Comment: I had never heard it put that way: “probability density can exceed $1$”. Could that be playing a role in my two copula entropy questions from last year? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511088/mutual-information-relationship-to-copula-entropy-is-borked https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/510992/copula-entropy-calculation-is-borked